# How to apply validation on a user control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a ascx file in which i have placed the below code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="textboxDate" runat="server" CssClass="FieldValue" MaxLength="10"
Columns="12" autocomplete="off" Style="padding-right: 18px; border: 1px solid #567890;" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calendarExtenderDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="textboxDate"
PopupButtonID="textboxDate" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Enabled="false" ControlToValidate="textboxDate"
ID="valRequired" ErrorMessage="* This field is required" EnableClientScript="true"
Display="Dynamic" Text="*" />

<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="textboxDate"
Operator="DataTypeCheck" Display="Dynamic" Type="Date" ID="valValidDate" ErrorMessage="* Date is in an incorrect format"
Text="*" EnableClientScript="true" />


<asp:CustomValidator CssClass="error" Text="*" runat="server" ID="rangeVal" Display="dynamic" OnServerValidate="rangeVal_Validate" />
```

I'm calling this user control in one of my form by

```
 <uc:DateControl ID="dateControlStart" runat="server" RequiredErrorMessage="please enter date" />
```

So , i want if user select any date which is less than or equal to current date an error should come saying "incorrect error". I want to do this validation in the aspx page on client side not in user control. Can any one help me?

Comment: Why don't you change those ASP.Net validations to client side JavaScript functions?

Comment: I dont want to change these validations as this user control page is getting used in other form also. I just want to add new validation to my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="uxDateFormatValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dateControlStart$textboxDate"
Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Error" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDateAgainstMinDate"
 />

 function ValidateDateAgainstMinDate(oSrc, args) {
var dateParts = args.Value.split('.');// which separator do you use?
if (dateParts.length >= 3) {
    var day = dateParts[2];
    var month = dateParts[1] - 1; //this one rocks
    var year = dateParts[0];
    var date = new Date(year, month, day);
    var minDate = new Date(1900, 0, 1); // use just new Date(); for today
    args.IsValid = date >= minDate
        && date.getDate() == day
        && date.getMonth() == month
        && date.getFullYear() == year;
}
else {
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

}

CustomValidator have to insert in your page together  with your uc:DateControl

Comment: It is always showing error: Im using '/' seperator and using new date(). Im providing 12/10/2012 as input.

Comment: var minDate = new Date();
                minDate.setHours(0);
                minDate.setMinutes(0);
                minDate.setMilliseconds(0);
                minDate.setSeconds(0);

Comment: The only change needed in my case was:  var day = dateParts[1];
                 var month = dateParts[0] - 1;
                var year = dateParts[2];    As the format in which the input was given was mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Just one quick ques: Is it not possible to use range validator instead of custom validator in this scenario

Comment: Yes, I think it possible. But for date I usually use Custom Validator with javascript function. Somthig like this if (startDateTextBox && endDateTextBox) {
        if (startDateTextBox.val() && endDateTextBox.val()) {
            try {
                var startDate = getDateFromString(startDateTextBox.val());
                var endDate = getDateFromString(endDateTextBox.val());
                isValidDate = endDate > startDate;
            }
            catch (ex) { }
        }
    }